# How to use iCloud Photo Backup and still access specific videos while offline

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, photos

I use iCloud Photo backup for my photos. It's convenient. I can hold many thousands of photos and videos without overwhelming my iPhone memory storage.

It keeps a low res version of the photos, and it download the his-res only when necessary (e.g. when editing). For videos, it keeps a preview, and downloads the video when I request it.

However, I would like to access specific albums, containing both photos and videos, even while I'm offline.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: There should always be a low res on your phone, even when you are offline

Comment: Yes, there is for pictures, but not fore videos.